# SQL Log in error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a program that captures data from phone system and insert captured information into a database. this all works except that after some days (and the user id and password are known in advance!) the program starts to output error

**Event id 18546, severity 14, state 8**

(The above is "copied" from the MSSQL server activity log) indicating login failed for user. The issue is that has been working for some time, and then all of a sudden the above message starts to get output.

The fact that many programs use the same code to access the database, and one program seems to the go crazy after running a few days is frustrating. any ideas why this could be happening? or steps to determine likely cause?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "state 8" means "wrong password", so this should give you some indication where to start looking :)

Comment: The password of the user is reset after every some number of days? How do the application recover when this error starts popping up?

Comment: Check your security settings for the login in SQL Server, and whether or not the login is set to password expire rules etc.

Answer (score 0):

Error 18546 is related to login failed. The state is 8 that means, there is an issue in the password that you have entered.

Please check the password again.

Good Luck!